# How do I set a CoerceValueCallback for a control when it's bound to a DataView column

Tags: .net, dependency-properties, dataview

I have an application that I want to coerce a date value (call it DueDate) based on the value of another date entered by the user.  Using Dependency Properties, I know how to make this work by setting the CoerceValueCallback for the DueDate dependency property.  I need to bind to a DataView, though, and the only solution I can find is not to use dependency properties, but to instead use DataTableEvents.  Is this the right approach, or is there a better solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DataTableEvents seems to be the best approach.